# Close document in Mac Pages without saving or reverting

Tags: macos, iwork-pages

Is there any way to close a modified document in Mac Pages without either saving it or "reverting to the previous version" (beyond killing the process)?

We currently store our files on a network filesystem, and sometimes I will have a document 'open' (but not necessarily doing anything with it that I want to keep) and I want to be able to close it without modifying the file in any way.

As far as I can see, saving the document will overwrite the underlying file with the latest version that I have open, and reverting will also overwrite the file with the 'previous' version of what I have open. Both options appear to destroy anyone else's changes.

(i.e. the behaviour you'd get in MS Word where it doesn't modify the underlying file unless you specifically save it)

[Image showing save dialog with [revert changes][cancel][save] options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjX34.png) (not enough reputation to show image)

Comment: What happens when you just close it? If you made no changes there shouldn't even be any prompt. If you did, then 'don't save'.

Comment: @Tetsujin 'Just closing it' works in the case of no changes, but I may have made changes that I don't want to keep. I have attempted to update the question accordingly...